# How is excess semen removed if ejaculation does not occur?

Tags: reproduction

There are some attempts to answer the question that I found via cursory Google search, but none of them were appropriately sourced.

[This site](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/questions/question/2470/) claims that they are "recycled like blood cells", but the blood cells are recycled using the spleen, and I don't think spermatozoa normally enter the blood stream at any point in time.

[This other site](http://growingupboys.info/Answers/20070910b.html) contradicts the first site, and claims that they are removed from the body by "dripping" them, therefore expelling them in the normal urine stream.

What is the actual process through which semen is removed if ejaculation does not occur?

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as my knowledge goes in this aspect..

If sperms are not ejaculated then they are simply reabsorbed by the epididymis and recycled.
I would say the first website you have linked up there is what is a more appropriate explanation.